# How to pair Logitech Unifying devices to more than one transceiver

Tags: logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard, logitech-unifying-receiver

The Logitech unifying transceiver is great and I can connect multiple unifying devices to the same transceiver on my PC.

I recently discovered that the Unifying transceiver works with my ACER android tablet and gives me the ability to connect a REAL keyboard AND and REAL mouse to it.  This gives me fine control over a number of items.

However, I have a couple of these transceivers - so I'd like to be able to LEAVE one in the tablet and the other in the PC.

Assuming, for the present, that I'm using the PC and tablet one at a time (ie the other is switched off), is there any way I can use one set of keyboard & mouse to easily connect to the appropriate system?  The USB connector on the tablet is "tight" and a bit finicky and so I'm loath to move the existing transceiver between the systems.

Research on another site suggests that while the protocol could support this, the firmware is crippled to inhibit this.  However it has been suggested that one could "re-pair" by using the "Connect" button - except neither device has one.  The devices apparently remember the last pairing and need to have the Unifying software downloaded to the System to re-pair (and/or attach/detach) devices.  As far as I'm aware this doesn't exist for Android.

I'll try Logitech later today to see what they say - but I'm pretty sure I know what their answer will be.  They'll assert: "It Cayn't bee durn".  But I don't like to give up THAT easily... :)

TIA,
Paolo

Comment: As mentioned in the main post, contact with Logitech confirmed that "you can't pair a unifying device with more than one transceiver at a time".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same WIRELESS mouse + keyboard (Logitech Unifying) for two different computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/458876/same-wireless-mouse-keyboard-logitech-unifying-for-two-different-computers)

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately at logitech website, they said unifying software does not suport multiple transcever connection.
I actually tried myself. It will not work unless unplug and plus transceiver each time you switch from your computer to tablet.