# Same WIRELESS mouse + keyboard (Logitech Unifying) for two different computers?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-keyboard, wireless-mouse, trackball, logitech-unifying-receiver

I have a mouse and keyboard with the Logitech Unifying receiver.  I have two of those receivers, one in my desktop and one in my laptop.  It is quite a pain to actually unpair and repair the mouse+keyboard from one PC to the other.  (I think logitech did this on purpose so you would have to buy a second mouse+keyboard, who knows) .

In any event is there some hardware method of resolving this or some "hack" to be able to easily switch from one unifying receiver to the next quickly?

I have seen some post on superuser regarding softare such as input director or synergy but thought I would see if anyone has hardware solution first.

Regards

josh

Comment: Why not just move the receiver between the computers?

Comment: please see this question answer, https://superuser.com/a/1655417/1319010

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm going to answer no - it is not possible.  There appear to be similar questions on Logitech's site so you can search there as well.  I suspect the answer is that when you pair, the transceiver and the device exchange several bytes of random data and form a key to both allows the devices to recognize each other and to encrypt their wireless transmission.

The problem is that the transceiver may have the ability to recognize something like 5 devices, but the input devices can only recognize and pair to one transceiver.  That's because the transceiver only has to sit there and accept a signal it recognizes, otherwise it is passive.  Sit, if you see a signal with the correct encryption and ID, accept input, otherwise ignore.

If you added the ability to have the input devices (mouse, keyboard...) pair to multiple transceivers, you would require some sort of additional buttons on the device to switch between them.  You'd also need to have the input device store the state (caps lock, num lock...) it was in for each transceiver.

The only Logitech device that can do this is the new K760 keyboard for bluetooth.  None of the Unify devices appear able to do this.

Comment: This sucks, but it's also true. I sell lots of Logitec, and that is one question that always comes up. +1 though

Comment: this answer is outdated, and should be deleted , it was in 2012

Answer (score 9):

The new Logitech M720 has this feature:
http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/m720-triathlon
[image]

How I use it:

- Channel 1: Notebook (Unifying receiver)
- Channel 2: Android Smartphone (Bluetooth)
- Channel 3: Desktop PC (Unifying receiver - not included in box content)

Alternatives:

1. Some monitors have a built-in usb switch. Search for a monitor with two usb upstream ports:
   https://www.google.com/search?q=monitor+"two+upstream"
2. You could buy a KVM switch to switch multiple ports like video output, sound and USB or you could buy a usb switch (the cheapiest method).
3. Use for Windows the Mouse without Borders tool to use one mouse with multiple windows PCs:
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460
   Or use Teleport if you prefer Apple:
   http://abyssoft.com/software/teleport/
4. Buy a M720 and combine it with 3.) so you can control all your Apple and Windows devices with one mouse and keyboard ;)

Comment: Still no trackball version of this "switching" mouse  :(

Comment: recently purchased this (bundled with MK850 keyboard), turns out the switching feature is a *huge* plus

Comment: you can utilize this answer also https://superuser.com/a/1655417/1319010

Answer (score 3):

I solved this, to some extent, with AutoHotkey and figuring out what causes the de-pairing. This solution requires some seconds for re-pairing each time, but is fast enough to be a useful method.

The AutoHotkey code:

```
F2::
  Run, C:\Program Files\Common Files\Logishrd\Unifying\DJCUHost.exe ; this is the Unifying connection program
  WinWaitActive ahk_exe DJCUHost.exe,, 4
  If !ErrorLevel
  {                                            
    Sleep 160 ; 100 was not enough
    Send {Enter}
    TrayTip Re-pairing Logitech,To disconnect: pull dongle, hibernate or use a USB switch to disconnect the dongle
    ; As soon as you have re-paired, you can switch on (or re-insert or wake the computer with) the Unifying dongle to put it back into operation (it then waits for a missing pairing)
  }
  else
    TrayTip Could not open the Unifying connection program,`n
  Return
```

Basically that code is only opening the Unifying connection program, but speeds things up. The thing is to understand that the pairing is (temporarily) lost as soon as power is lost for the small Logitech Unifying dongle. Then, a new pairing can be done quickly. You can achive the required power loss by: 1) pulling the dongle out, 2) using a USB hub with simple toggle switches (or a KVM Switch), 3) putting the computer into hibernation, after which the dongle loses power (you can't have the dongle on a permanently powered USB hub for this to work, also just sleep might be enough if you set your computer to cut the power to the dongle during sleep). (There's also option 4, you can go to Logitech Unifying Software: Advanced, Un-Pair. But that can't be done blindly, though in some cases a script could do that un-pairing.)

So, using the option 2 or 3 is just more convenient than removing the dongle from the computer that needs to get un-paired, especially if your setup is like mine where the dongle is located in a hard to reach place.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved easily using a $6 USB manual switcher...That is sharing a single keyboard/Mouse etc via a single Unifying receiver, you need a power USB hub as well

Comment: This answer needs a lot more clarification. How can it be achieved easily? What connects to what, and how does it all work?

Comment: @ossulic you get an USB switch; connect one end to one PC and the second to the other; you plug in the receiver in the switch and choose which PC it should connect to - by using the switch.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose two receivers (eg. installed in a PC and a laptap) could unify successfully and pair with a keyboard - and then the keyboard is "used" while *both* machines are on and within RF range ...

Or worse, unifying by tripling / quadrupling ... receivers, each installed on a unique host, to a single device which would then be "used" simultaneously by all the hosts, within RF range, that are on  ... hmmm ....

Migrating the receiver back and forth between the two machines is easier - after all, it is desired that the big pieces of hardware (K & M)  do so (ie. migrate between the machines)  and the receiver can be conveniently stored in one of them until reinserted in the target host machine's USB port.  However, the anecdote in [Logitech unifying reciever no longer works on ALL USB ports](https://superuser.com/questions/455403/logitech-unifying-reciever-no-longer-works-on-all-usb-ports) and information from [USB port may stop working after you remove or insert a USB device](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817900) implies  possible USB connection failure either from mechanical insertion / extraction damage ([USB type A duty cycle is approx. 1500 connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Standard_connectors) ) or transient software malfunction of the receiver's USB registration.

related: [How to pair Logitech Unifying devices to more than one transceiver](https://superuser.com/questions/398609/how-to-pair-logitech-unifying-devices-to-more-than-one-transceiver)

Answer (score 1):

Recent Logitech devices support a new technology that is called [Logitech Flow](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/options/page/flow-multi-device-control). This allows you to create one central work station for multiple computers. Your keyboard follows your cursor from one computer to another, meaning you can type on multiple devices in one fluid workflow. The requirements are that the devices support the technology (unfortunately older devices do not), and that the computers are connected to the same network. The integration is managed by a special software that also needs to be installed.

Apart from the Flow technology, as indicated above, recent Logitech keyboards and mice give you the possibility to choose one out of 3 possible computers to work with through some enumerated keys.

Comment: "recent Logitech keyboards and mice give you the possibility" - not just "recent", but "high-end", aka "expensive". Useful answer anyway, people who *really* need it should be able to shell out extra. And the rest of people should know what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Synergy before with great results. From their About Page it was

> Born out of frustration with KVM switches...

It's not free (~$30 for personal use) but is much less expensive than purchasing newer hardware (currently the trackball is still not available from Logitech that is able to store multiple connections)

Hope this helps out!

[Synergy Webaite](https://symless.com/synergy)

Comment: Since Synergy is mentioned I'd like to point to https://github.com/debauchee/barrier
An open-source software ‘KVM’ switch (they share the same origin).