# Switching Logitech mouse and keyboard between two computers (Logitech Flow not working since work computer is on a VPN)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse, logitech-keyboard, logitech-unifying-receiver

I have the Logitech MX Keys and MX Master 3 and was hoping to use Logitech Flow in order to use my work computer and personal computer at the same time.

Unfortunately, my work computer is locked down and requires a VPN and so I don't seem to be able to use Flow. I was wondering if there is any work around for this, or if I simply won't be able to use Flow.

If using Flow won't be an option, is there an easier way to switch my keyboard and mouse between computers? Currently I have to lift up my mouse and cycle through to the computer I want to use, and same with the keyboard. Is there any type of shortcut I could create to make switching easier (ie. pressing one button on my keyboard to switch both my mouse and keyboard over)?

Comment: You would need to explain your need to company support and see if they will install the keyboard / mouse for you.

Comment: That's not problem @john, I can install Logitech Options and also have the mouse & keyboard setup and working on my work computer. The issue is that Logitech Flow requires both computers to be on the same network and my work computer can't access my home network and must go through the VPN.

Comment: I don't think there will be a work around for using Flow, but I wanted to ask just in case there is. And if not, if there is a clever solution to make switching between computers easier than having to lift up my mouse and cycle through the options, and repeat with my keyboard. Ie. can I switch my computer and mouse to the other computer by clicking one button on my keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

This question is open for many opinions and different answers, so here goes my 2 cents.

Since you cannot have access to your local network from your work computer, you need to have a hardware based solution:

**Buy a new Logi Keyboard/Mouse combo with switch buttons:**

IMO this is your best option. Personally I have a MK850 Keyboard and Mouse Combo (K850 keyboard + M720 mouse) and both are compatible with more than one Unify USB receptor (also Bluetooth without a new dongle). They have special key/buttons to switch from one receiver to another, but you'll need to press it on the keyboard AND on the mouse - if you don't, your keyboard could be attached to one receiver and your mouse to another. But, it is a pretty simple design, you'll get used to it.

**Buy a USB hardware KVM**

This reminds me the old days on tower servers without special server KVMs. You can plug your single USB keyboard and USB mouse of any brand into the available "client" USB ports and connect the "server" USB ports on each computer. Then, you simply press one button on the KVM to switch from one to another. All USB devices connected into "client" ports will be attached to only one computer at time.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the same issue.

In my case I have Cisco AnyConnect as a VPN client and there I can enable "Allow local(lan) access when using VPN". To access this menu, click the gear icon at the bottom left for "Advanced Settings" and check the options in the "VPN" tab. It does still need to be something your network admin configured, but it worked on my VPN.

[image: Image of the Advanced Settings VPN menu]

Now Logitech Flow works for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier), which is an open-source software KVM, for the same functionality provided by Logitech flow, with the added benefit of being able to explicitly connect over IPv6 on your LAN, while your VPN routes only IPv4 traffic.

This 'setup' hinges on the fact that *most* VPN applications that I have encountered create a virtual network adapter on which you can disable IPv6 routing. To do this on Windows you can [configure the VPN virtual adapter to disable IPv6](https://adamtheautomator.com/disable-ipv6/) while still leaving it enabled on your physical network adapter.

*I'm not certain how VPN clients work on other platforms, and whether similar configuration can be applied, this would be left as an exercise for the reader.*

After disabling IPv6 on your virtual/vpn adapter, configure your [Barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier) **client** to connect to whichever computer is the **server** using the **server's IPv6 address** which you can get using the `ipconfig` command.